# Measuring the observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, observables

I am working through this quantum mechanics homework question and I am a little confused on what I am being asked to do. I have come to one of two possible answers but I don't think either is correct.

Say you have a ket $\psi$ I am asked to find the possible outcomes of measuring the observable values of the operators given in the problem.

I have already shown that they are Hermitian. But I am not sure if I am supposed to calculate the *expected* values of the operator $\Omega$.
where the expecred value is found by $<\Omega> = <\psi|\Omega|\psi>$
I don't think this is correct because the problem asks for the outcomes of measuring the obersvable**s**.

So then I thought maybe because I diagonalized $\Omega$ all I need to do is show that the observables are the eigenvalues of the operator? Which are just down the diagonal of $\Omega$. But again I am suspicious of this because then I am asked to find the probability of each of the observables and I am not sure how to do that with just knowing *that* they are observable. Don't I need like an observation state ket or something like that? Something that would go in the equation: 
$P(\omega)= |<\psi|\omega>|^2$ I tried to find some stuff online but some of the online solutions seem to do the reverse order for $\psi$ and $\omega$ to find the probability.

Which of these methods is correct to measure the observables? Or am I completely off?

Comment: Hint: try to relate $\omega$ to your operator

Comment: Relating it to the operator would be like finding the column vector corresponding to the eigenvector of that eigenvalue???
Like: $|\omega>=$ (Eigenvector)?

Comment: Yup. That’s right.

Comment: To make sure I am understanding correctly: 
Do I just do the inner product of the $\psi$ and the $|\omega>$?
So the possible outcomes of $\Omega$ would be $<\omega_1|\psi>$ and then the same thing for $|\omega_2>$ and $|\omega_3>$? The result of those three inner products would be the posible outcomes of measuring the observables?

Comment: Outcomes would always be an eigenstate (of that operator) with the observable being the corresponding eigenvalue. The probability of each of them is given by your $P$ expression. Remember that inner products are just (complex) numbers.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, is the eigenstate just the corresponding eigenvector of the observable?

Comment: Yes. Eigenstate is the eigenvector. They are synonyms. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: So it is correct to say that I could take the inner products between the $\psi$ and each of the eigenstates?

Thank you so much for your help!